# While moving <div>s around using Jquery, insertAfter() works but insertBefore() does not

Tags: html, jquery, dom

I am moving  elements around in the DOM using Jquery. I can click the down arrow on the top  (Plastic Card) and it moves down but I cannot click the up arrow on the bottom  (Paper Insert) and have that  move up. It does nothing. No action in the DOM at all. Strange. Why?

The Jquery functions are essentially reflections of each other. I would imagine they both should work fine for their respective intentions.

[image]

HTML Code:

```
        <div class="item">
            <div class="item_detail" style="display:flex;">
                <div class="item_trigger">
                    <a href="#" class="" style="display:inline;" title="Item"><img class="item_image" src="~/Content/Images/item.svg" /></a>
                    <h3 style="font-size: 16px; width:70%; display:inline;">Insert with Plastic Card</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="actions" style="color:white; ">
                    <a id="btnAddNewComponent" class="actionBtn">
                        <img class="selector" style="" src="~/Content/Images/component.svg" title="Add New Component" />
                    </a>
                    <a id="btnEdit" class="actionBtn">
                        <img class="selector" style="" src="~/Content/Images/edit.svg" title="Edit Selected Item" />
                    </a>
                    <a id="btnUp" class="actionBtn">
                        <img class="selector" style="" src="~/Content/Images/up-arrow.svg" title="Move Selected Item Up" />
                    </a>
                    <a id="btnDown" class="actionBtn">
                        <img class="selector" style="" src="~/Content/Images/down-arrow.svg" title="Move Selected Item Down" />
                    </a>
                    <a id="btnTrash" class="actionBtn">
                        <img class="selector" style="" src="~/Content/Images/delete.svg" title="Delete Selected Item" />
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="plusMinusIcon">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="component component_trigger" style="margin-bottom:10px; display:none; padding-top:0; padding-left:0;">
                <a href="#" class="" style="display:inline; border-radius:5px; padding:4px;"><img class="component_image" src="~/Content/Images/component.svg" /></a>
                <h2 style="font-size: 14px; display:inline;">Paper Insert</h2>
                <div class="componentActions" style="color:white; float:right;">
                    <a id="btnEdit" class="actionBtn">
                        <img class="btnComponentEdit" style="" src="~/Content/Images/edit.svg" title="Edit Selected Item" />
                    </a>
                    <a id="btnUp" class="actionBtn">
                        <img class="btnComponentUp" style="" src="~/Content/Images/up-arrow.svg" title="Move Selected Item Up" />
                    </a>
                    <a id="btnDown" class="actionBtn">
                        <img class="btnComponentDown" style="" src="~/Content/Images/down-arrow.svg" title="Move Selected Item Down" />
                    </a>
                    <a id="btnTrash" class="actionBtn">
                        <img class="btnComponentTrash" style="" src="~/Content/Images/delete.svg" title="Delete Selected Item" />
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="component component_trigger" style="margin-bottom:10px; display:none; padding-top:0; padding-left:0;">
                <a href="#" class="" style="display:inline; border-radius:5px; padding:4px;"><img class="component_image" src="~/Content/Images/component.svg" /></a>
                <h2 style="font-size: 14px; display:inline;">Plastic Card</h2>
                <div class="componentActions" style="color:white; float:right;">
                    <a id="btnEdit" class="actionBtn">
                        <img class="btnComponentEdit" style="" src="~/Content/Images/edit.svg" title="Edit Selected Item" />
                    </a>
                    <a id="btnUp" class="actionBtn">
                        <img class="btnComponentUp" style="" src="~/Content/Images/up-arrow.svg" title="Move Selected Item Up" />
                    </a>
                    <a id="btnDown" class="actionBtn">
                        <img class="btnComponentDown" style="" src="~/Content/Images/down-arrow.svg" title="Move Selected Item Down" />
                    </a>
                    <a id="btnTrash" class="actionBtn">
                        <img class="btnComponentTrash" style="" src="~/Content/Images/delete.svg" title="Delete Selected Item" />
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).on('click', '.btnComponentDown', function () {
    var componentSelected = $(this).parent().parent().parent();
    var currentParentItem = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent();
    $(componentSelected).next().insertAfter($(componentSelected).prev());
    $(currentParentItem).children().last('.component').children().children('.componentActions a[id=btnDown]').css('display', 'none');
    $(currentParentItem).children().last('.component').children().children('.componentActions a[id=btnUp]').css('display', 'block');
    $(currentParentItem).children('.component').first().children('.componentActions').children('a[id=btnUp]').css('display', 'none');
    $(currentParentItem).children('.component').first().children('.componentActions').children('a[id=btnDown]').css('display', 'block');
});

$(document).on('click', '.btnComponentUp', function () {
    var componentSelected = $(this).parent().parent().parent();
    var currentParentItem = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent();
    $(componentSelected).prev().insertBefore($(componentSelected).next());
    $(currentParentItem).children().last('.component').children().children('.componentActions a[id=btnDown]').css('display', 'none');
    $(currentParentItem).children().last('.component').children().children('.componentActions a[id=btnUp]').css('display', 'block');
    $(currentParentItem).children('.component').first().children('.componentActions').children('a[id=btnUp]').css('display', 'none');
    $(currentParentItem).children('.component').first().children('.componentActions').children('a[id=btnDown]').css('display', 'block');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found another format for the `insertBefore` and `insertAfter` functions. That DOES work. I was using:

```
$(componentSelected).prev().insertBefore($(componentSelected).next());
```

I changed it to:

```
$(componentSelected).insertBefore($(componentSelected).prev('.component'));
```

And the opposite is true for the insertAfter() code I had. I changed:

```
$(componentSelected).next().insertAfter($(componentSelected).prev());
```

to:

```
$(componentSelected).insertAfter($(componentSelected).next('.component'));
```

Refer to:  https://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/

```
This line opened my eyes:  $( "**\<p>Test\</p>**" ).insertBefore( "**.inner**" );
```

Clearly, you put the HTML in the first part and the target in the second part of the instruction.